# PXE Client-Error via WDS: 'boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi' not found

Tags: wds

I installed Windows Deployment Services (WDS) on a new Server 2012 R2 machine. 
My Hyper-V (Gen2, UEFI, Secure Boot) clients fail at requesting 'boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi' via TFTP. The server responds that the file was not found.

I can confirm that 'C:\RemoteInstall\Boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi' is indeed missing. Everything else is there.

I tried installing a Server 2016 and configuring WDS, but the file is missing there, too.

Why is that file missing and what must I do to get PXE running?

Comment: Can you remove and add the WDS role to your machine? It may regenerate the boot file properly. How to reset WDS: https://serverfault.com/questions/916163/windows-application-log-persistent-errors-binlsvc-1284/917677#917677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a top from a Redditor. WDS is supposed to add those files once you add a Windows boot.wim to the boot images. However, this is broken with Windows 10 v1803. I used an earlier ISO and WDS copied the files over to that directory. Very frustrating.

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  Imported boot.wim from Windows 10 1607 which added a bunch of missing files to boot\x64\